# Reserve FPU stack for clobbering in inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, x87

When writing math functions in inline assembly, is there a way of telling the compiler "I use 2 extra slots of the FPU-stack"?

For example a exp implementation might look like this:

```cpp
    asm("fldl2e\n"
        "fmulp\n"
        "fld1\n"
        "fld %%st(1)\n"
        "fprem\n"
        "f2xm1\n"
        "faddp\n"
        "fscale\n"
        "fstp %%st(1)"
        : "=t"(res)
        : "0"(exponent));
```

but the compiler does not know that the maximum stack used by this function is 3 slots and might have already filled it up with 6 other values before loading the exponent onto it, leaving not enough for the calculations.
Is just "clobber st(2),st(1),st(0)" the right way to do it,
or is there a different/better way to do it

Comment: Have you already read 6.47.2.9, "x86 Floating-Point asm Operands", of [the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)?

Comment: If I read it correctly, I would just clobber st2 and st3 in the described case?

Comment: st1 and st2 would be my reading, but I'm not certain.